# Anchor hud pane on camera bounds

Tags: game-engine

Is there a way to figure out the frustum bounds of an orthographic camera using Blender Game Engine?

I'm trying to anchor some panels on the corners of the screen without success .

I'm working with two scenes , one with a camera perspective and another with the orthographic camera ( hud )

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a good question. If you can add a screenshot of what you're trying to accomplish, it'd be even betterer.

Comment: ...and welcome to B.SE, btw!

Answer (score 1):

Here is where you set it:

[image]

It says 7.314, therefore the camera is 7.314 wide.

As to doing it in real-time, the python API you are looking for is [camera.orthoscale](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_2/bge.types.KX_Camera.html#bge.types.KX_Camera.ortho_scale) to get the width of the camera.

Sample code (untested):

```
aspect_ratio = bge.render.getScreenHeight() / bge.render.getScreenWidth()
height = aspect_ratio * camera.orthoscale
top_right = camera.getAxisVect([width/2, height/2, 0.5])
bottom_left = camera.getAxisVect([-width/2, -height/2, 0.5])
```

Note that the 0.5's in the getAxisVect are to place the object slightly forwards of the camera to ensure it get's viewed.